# transforming problems into Diophantine equations

Tags: prime-numbers, diophantine-equations

Several questions in number theory deals with primes. For example, the twin prime conjecture states that $2=p_{n+1}-p_{n}$ infinitely many times. I know that $(p_{n})_{n≥1}$ is a sequence. But I am asking if one can consider this problem as a **Diophantine equation** (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation.html). The same question is for the **Goldbach's conjecture** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture).

In other words: Consider the equation: $$x-y-2=0.....(*)$$

Then the twin prime conjecture is true if and only if this equation has infinitely many pairs of primes solutions in $x$ and $y$.

More generally, I am asking if there exist a problem related to primes which is not transformable to a Diophantine equation.

Comment: There is a set of Diophantine equations such that given integer is prime if and only if those equations have a solution. - [Prime Diophantine Equations](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeDiophantineEquations.html). Does this answer your question?

Comment: I would not consider $2=p_{n+1}-p_n$ to be a Diophantine equation. The problem, "are primes interesting", is not transformable into a Diophantine equation.

Comment: @GerryMyerson; and what about the equation (*).

Comment: What makes an equation *Diophantine* is that you insist on integer (or, occasionally, rational) solutions. Once you say you want only *prime* solutions, it's not a Diophantine equation any more. The techniques that apply to Diophantine equations won't work.

Comment: Understood, Germany?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Yes. Thank you very much.